# Encoder number of outpus for opcode within a MIPS machine instruction

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, digital-logic

If I have an encoder with 8 data inputs, what is its maximum number of outputs?

I know that an encoder is a combinational circuit that performs the reverse operation of a decoder. It has a maximum of **2^n** input lines and ‘n’ output lines, hence it encodes the information from **2^n** inputs into an n-bit code. Since I have 8 data input, the output will be 3, since **2^3 = 8**. Is that the correct assumption?

Comment: Its not *maximum* number of outputs, it is the exact (or minimum) number. Otherwise its correct. Not sure how it is related to MIPS or programming in general.

Comment: It's for opcodes in a MIPS processor.

Comment: There aren't any 3-bit fields in MIPS machine instructions.  Just like [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68070486/minimum-number-of-input-bits-required-by-a-circuit-to-decode), you have it backwards.  Unless you're actually talking about encoding the opcode field based on one of 2^6 different possible instructions.  But you wouldn't normally be using a digital-logic encoder to *generate* a MIPS instruction.  Normally machine-code is generated by software, e.g. using a hash table to map text strings like `xori` to integer values that are *already* in binary.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to tease apart the concepts of *[one hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)* (decoded) lines and an encoding using a number of bits.  Both these concepts are a way to represent information, but their form and typical usage is different.

One hot is a technique wherein at most one line is 1/true and all the other lines are 0/false.  These one hot lines are *not considered digits in a number*, but rather individual *signals* or conditions (only one of which is can be true at any given time).  This form is particularly useful in certain circuits, as each of the one hot lines can activate some other hardware.  (A hardware lookup table ([LUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Hardware_LUTs)), a RAM or ROM may use one-hot within its internal array indexing.)

Encoding is a technique where we use N lines as digits in an N-bit number, as would be found in a CPU register holding a number, or as we might write normal binary numbers in text.  By contrast, in this form any of the N bits can be 1 (or 0).

Simple encoders & decoders translate between encoded form (N-bit numbers) and one hot form (2<sup>N</sup> lines).

> ... encoder ... has a maximum of 2^n input lines and ‘n’ output lines

In your statement, the 2^n input lines *are in one hot form*, while the output lines are normal numbers in binary (i.e. encoded).

Both the inputs (2^n lines) and the outputs (n lines) are capable of representing exactly ***2^n*** different values!  As a result, decode/encode is a 1:1 mapping, back & forth.  (It would be an error to have multiple hots on the input side of such a decoder, and bad things would happen in a system that allowed that.)

In the formulas you're speaking to:  2<sup>N</sup> = V,  and   N = log<sub>2</sub> ( V )  —  N stands for number of bits (a bit is a *binary* **digit**), and V stands for number of values that can be represented in N bits.

(While the 2's in these formulas are for *binary* — substitute 2 with 10 for the same relationships for number of *decimal digits* vs. number of values those number of digits can represent/store/communicate).

In one hot form we need V number of lines, whereas in encoded form we need N lines (as bits/digits) to represent the same information (one of V different values).

Consider whether a number you're looking is a digit count (as with N) or a value count (as with V).

And bear in mind that in one hot form, we need one line for each possible value, V (whereas in encoded form we need N bits for V possible values).

---

A MIPS processor will feed the 6 bit opcode field into a lookup table of some sort, in order to determine which set of control signals to activate for any given instruction.  (The opcode field is not one hot, but rather a bit field of N=6 bits).

These control signals are (also) not one hot, and the MIPS instruction decoder is not using a simple decoder, but rather a mapper that goes between encoded opcode values and effectively encoded control signals — this mapping is accomplished by lookup in a table.

These control signals are individual boolean values rather than as a set either one-hot or an encoded number.  One hot may be used internally in indexing of this mapping.  This mapping is basically an array lookup where the index is the opcode and each array element has all the individual control signal values appropriate its index.

(R-Type instructions all share a common opcode value, so when the R-Type opcode value is present, then additional lookup/mapping is done on the func bit field to generate the proper control signals.)